# MATLAB sparse matrix GEVP

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue, eigenvector

Is there a way/function/code to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a sparse matrix (possibly a large matrix as well) in MATLAB? The Generalized Eigenvalue problem needs to be solved and  using `eig` results in errors due to singularity.

Comment: Are you using an actual `sparse` matrix type? If so, `eigs` should be able to handle this

Comment: [`eigs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) might better for sparse matrices, but I'm not sure that'll have any less singularities.

Comment: I'm converting it into a full matrix and passing to `eigs` but the singularity issue persists.